# Magento 2.0 API response is not in JSON format

Tags: magento-2.0

Unable to get response in JSON format with POST/PUT requests for adding/updating a Product to the category

Reference link: http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/

API: catalogCategoryLinkRepositoryV1 -> /V1/categories/{categoryId}/products

End point URL ->  http:///rest/default/V1/categories/4/products

Header:

Content-Type: application/json
Authorization:

Request body:

```
{
  "productLink": {
    "sku": "Happiest_Minds_Bag",
    "position": 0,
    "categoryId": "4",
    "extensionAttributes": {}
  }
}
```

Response: "true"

The response which I get is a plain string "true" with status code "200 OK". But for any other error status code for this request I get a proper JSON response.

Why am I not getting response in JSON format for status code "200 OK"?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add  **'Accept' => 'application/json',**
   **'Content-Type' => 'application/json'**

for example,

```
$token = '4hmpioj8qvtgh1d06ujgg52a52yqbmye';
$httpHeaders = new \Zend\Http\Headers();

$httpHeaders->addHeaders([
   'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
   'Accept' => 'application/json',
   'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
]);
```

Comment: We did the same but still we are getting the same "true" as response      'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
   'Accept' => 'application/json',
   'Content-Type' => 'application/json'

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to receive a JSON response, you must set the `Accept` header of your request to `application/json`.

Comment: Tried setting Accept: application/json as header. Still the response is string "true".

Comment: The string "true" IS json. That's what you'd get from `json_encode(true)`. It sounds like you're expecting the object you created back, but doesn't sound like that's how it works.

Comment: I am trying to parse it by using JAVA but getting exception because of a simple string. We are expecting the format in  {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
    {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
    {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
]}